# PHP IMAP and XOAUTH 

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I want to access gmail IMAP using XOAUTH with PHP.
http://code.google.com/intl/uk/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html#imap

I tried samples from page above and i can get get token for AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH .
But i don't know how to include this token in IMAP requests.
I use http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php    library to access IMAP.
Seems this PHP extension doesn't allow to use some alternate AUTHENTICATE methods.
Is this possible to use XOAUTH with this IMAP extension?

If no then what can i do there? Is it possible to create some alternate function for imap_open that will return some handle taht later can be used with all another functions of this extension?

Answer (score 1):

Standard PHP extension doesn't support XOAUTH. [handmadeimap](https://github.com/petewarden/handmadeimap) library, however, might be useful - it has example of doing oauth authentication against Google.

Comment: Thanks.I already have PHP class that supports XOAUTH. But the problem is that my existent application is build on base of Standard PHP IMAP extension. I can't easy replace it . I use many functions that have no alternatives in pure PHP imap classes. Ex. imap_fetchstructure is used in my application and i can't find any other PHP class that has the same function.

Comment: Could you tell me what is that php class that supports XOAUTH?

Answer (score 1):

As a lot of people will hit this question. So Using php_sockets Implemented a simple library. Hopefully will act as required. Delete mail function is not yet added. But you can take a look if it satisfies your need. Try example. https://github.com/vmuthal/VivOAuthIMAP