# webklex laravel imap not connected to gmail

Tags: php, laravel, imap

I have enabled pop as well as imap on my gmail account which I am using for testing to read inbox using imap and pop in php.

However, I have successfully connected with other server and read emails from those server but gmail is blocking the connection and throwing the errors as given below:

imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}. Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,993: Connection timed out; Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,993: No route to host; Can't connect to imap.gmail.com,993: Network is unreachable

i am using Webklex/laravel-imap package

Comment: Well there's `no route to host` and `network unreachable` the first could be because of a DNS issue, then the second not makes it seem like your development server doesn't have internet access at all, are you sure it does?

Comment: yes i have an internet access and i fetched emails on other server properly but not on that server. and how to check that it is DNS or other issue

Comment: Probably a firewall on your host.

Answer (score 0):

[Webklex/laravel-imap](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap) doesn't support XOAUTH as Gmail says that you now need to interact with their implementation of the imap protocol as they note here [Gmail - IMAP, POP, and SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp)

A Github issue has already been raised [Webklex/laravel-imap/issues/180](https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap/issues/180) which leads us back to this [Stackoverflow - PHP IMAP and XOAUTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089614/php-imap-and-xoauth)
.

I would suggest that you implement a different client for working with Gmail, you can try one of these packages:

- [pulkitjalan/google-apiclient](https://github.com/pulkitjalan/google-apiclient)
- [github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client)
- [dacastro4/laravel-gmail](https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail)